# Concatenate multiple rows of data into 1 column, but grouping it based on two primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

can anyone help me combine rows of stock location into 1 column

based on branch and productid primary keys
im not sure what i can try as the code below just runs and runs

do i need to self join to get the result? is there a better method than below?

before

```
branch  productid  stock-location
1           5           b5
1           3           b2
1           5           b4
```

after

```
branch  productid  stock-location
1           5           b5,b4
1           3           b2
```

here is my very bad code

```
SELECT Main.zone,
      LEFT(Main.zone,Len(Main.zone)-1) As "ZONE_CODE"
FROM
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT ST2.LOCATION_NBR, 
          (
                SELECT ST1.ZONE_CODE + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.OPAL_ZONE ST1
                WHERE ST1.LOCATION_NBR = ST2.LOCATION_NBR
                ORDER BY ST1.LOCATION_NBR
                FOR XML PATH ('')
           ) zone
        FROM dbo.OPAL_ZONE sT2
   ) [Main]
```

Comment: Update- the script i posted runs, but all it did was group all the stock locations  based on the branch , but not the product.. so i think im close?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, sorry for the dud question, but i hope my answer can help someone else

```
       Main.Zone_Loc As "ZONE_CODE"
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ST2.LOCATION_NBR, st2.PRODUCT_CODE,
            (
                SELECT ST1.ZONE_CODE + ',' AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.OPAL_ZONE ST1
                WHERE ST1.LOCATION_NBR = ST2.LOCATION_NBR and ST1.PRODUCT_CODE = sT2.PRODUCT_CODE
                ORDER BY ST1.LOCATION_NBR
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) [Zone_Loc]
        FROM dbo.OPAL_ZONE sT2
    ) [Main]
```